# What does "being let go" mean?

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, british-english

I am wondering what is the meaning of this sentence.

- You are not being let go.

For me it can have two meanings:

1. You are not allowed to leave
2. You are not asked to go

But, I don't know which one is accurate?

Is it even a correct sentence?

Comment: Fired, laid off, made redundant.

Comment: More context would help. Normally in the US it means you still have a job. Why is someone telling you this? Are others getting laid off? Are you in an airplane dangling  above a volcano?

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in the
singular or *“**these** Xes”* in the plural in many common and less
exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners don’t realize
that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this, that, these,
those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2nd one seems to be more accurate. "Let go" is commonly used as a 'nice' way of saying that you were fired or laid off. Therefore 'You are not being let go.' seems to be pointing towards the fact that you are not being asked to go, hence not fired/laid off.